# Troubles using JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, jupyter-notebook, importerror

im having troubles while using JupyterNotebook.

When I try to import SciPy and NumPy while using JupyterNotebook im always getting Errors:

```
import scipy as sp 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6b0df46be2d8> in <module>
----> 1 import scipy as sp

~\Anaconda3\envs\MachineL\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
     60 __all__ = ['test']
     61 
---> 62 from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
     63 if show_numpy_config is None:
     64     raise ImportError(

ImportError: cannot import name 'show_config'
```

And when I try to check if NumPy works:

```
import numpy as np
print("I like", np.pi)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dbcfc58336e0> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 print("I like", np.pi)

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'pi'
```

But the really confusing thing is that everything works when I try everything in a terminal.

```
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> print(sp.__version__)
1.3.1
```

or

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print("I like", np.pi)
I like 3.141592653589793
```

And I dont know what the problem could be... 
I first thought that my JupyterNotebook would use a different VirtualEnvironment so I tried this:

(In JupyterNotebook):

```
pip list
Package              Version  
-------------------- ---------
absl-py              0.8.1    
astor                0.8.0    
attrs                19.2.0   
backcall             0.1.0    
bleach               3.1.0    
certifi              2019.9.11
colorama             0.4.1    
cycler               0.10.0   
decorator            4.4.0    
defusedxml           0.6.0    
entrypoints          0.3      
gast                 0.2.2    
google-pasta         0.1.7    
grpcio               1.24.1   
h5py                 2.10.0   
ipykernel            5.1.2    
ipython              7.8.0    
ipython-genutils     0.2.0    
jedi                 0.15.1   
Jinja2               2.10.3   
jsonschema           3.0.2    
jupyter-client       5.3.4    
jupyter-core         4.6.0    
Keras-Applications   1.0.8    
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0    
kiwisolver           1.1.0    
Markdown             3.1.1    
MarkupSafe           1.1.1    
matplotlib           3.1.1    
mistune              0.8.4    
nbconvert            5.6.0    
nbformat             4.4.0    
notebook             6.0.1    
numpy                1.17.3   
opt-einsum           3.1.0    
pandas               0.25.1   
pandocfilters        1.4.2    
parso                0.5.1    
pickleshare          0.7.5    
pip                  19.2.3   
prometheus-client    0.7.1    
prompt-toolkit       2.0.10   
protobuf             3.10.0   
Pygments             2.4.2    
pyparsing            2.4.2    
pyrsistent           0.15.4   
python-dateutil      2.8.0    
pytz                 2019.3   
pywin32              223      
pywinpty             0.5.5    
pyzmq                18.1.0   
scipy                1.3.1    
Send2Trash           1.5.0    
setuptools           41.4.0   
six                  1.12.0   
tensorboard          2.0.0    
tensorflow           2.0.0    
tensorflow-estimator 2.0.0    
termcolor            1.1.0    
terminado            0.8.2    
testpath             0.4.2    
tornado              6.0.3    
traitlets            4.3.3    
wcwidth              0.1.7    
webencodings         0.5.1    
Werkzeug             0.16.0   
wheel                0.33.6   
wincertstore         0.2      
wrapt                1.11.2
```

And then I tried the same thing in my VirtualEnvironment:

```
Package              Version  
-------------------- ---------
absl-py              0.8.1    
astor                0.8.0    
attrs                19.2.0   
backcall             0.1.0    
bleach               3.1.0    
certifi              2019.9.11
colorama             0.4.1    
cycler               0.10.0   
decorator            4.4.0    
defusedxml           0.6.0    
entrypoints          0.3      
gast                 0.2.2    
google-pasta         0.1.7    
grpcio               1.24.1   
h5py                 2.10.0   
ipykernel            5.1.2    
ipython              7.8.0    
ipython-genutils     0.2.0    
jedi                 0.15.1   
Jinja2               2.10.3   
jsonschema           3.0.2    
jupyter-client       5.3.4    
jupyter-core         4.6.0    
Keras-Applications   1.0.8    
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0    
kiwisolver           1.1.0    
Markdown             3.1.1    
MarkupSafe           1.1.1    
matplotlib           3.1.1    
mistune              0.8.4    
nbconvert            5.6.0    
nbformat             4.4.0    
notebook             6.0.1    
numpy                1.17.3
opt-einsum           3.1.0    
pandas               0.25.1   
pandocfilters        1.4.2    
parso                0.5.1    
pickleshare          0.7.5    
pip                  19.2.3   
prometheus-client    0.7.1    
prompt-toolkit       2.0.10   
protobuf             3.10.0   
Pygments             2.4.2    
pyparsing            2.4.2    
pyrsistent           0.15.4   
python-dateutil      2.8.0    
pytz                 2019.3   
pywin32              223      
pywinpty             0.5.5    
pyzmq                18.1.0   
scipy                1.3.1    
Send2Trash           1.5.0    
setuptools           41.4.0   
six                  1.12.0   
tensorboard          2.0.0    
tensorflow           2.0.0    
tensorflow-estimator 2.0.0    
termcolor            1.1.0    
terminado            0.8.2    
testpath             0.4.2    
tornado              6.0.3    
traitlets            4.3.3    
wcwidth              0.1.7    
webencodings         0.5.1    
Werkzeug             0.16.0   
wheel                0.33.6   
wincertstore         0.2      
wrapt                1.11.2
```

The python version im using:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 14:00:49) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

This output is equally to the output of my terminal

And after I tried this I was pretty sure that both use the same VirtualEnvironment, so I dont really know what I should try anymore.

**Thank you for your time**, I hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Can you try a !pip install numpy in Jupyter notebooks on a new module and then compare the list of libraries again just to verify the CMD / Jupiter note books are working in the same enviorment?

Comment: @Ian-Fogelman I just tried that.
In Jupyter Notebook:
`
!pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\kampet\anaconda3\envs\machinel\lib\site-packages (1.17.3)
`
Just for testing I tried that in my terminal too:
`
(MachineL) C:\Users\Kampet>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\kampet\anaconda3\envs\machinel\
lib\site-packages (1.17.3)
`

I hope that this was what u meant.

Comment: Why cant i format my code lol.. sry im pretty new to Stackoverflow. btw ty for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there perhaps a numpy.py script anywhere in your Jupiter notebook directory? This could be taking priority over the actual numpy module. Try to change the directory that your working in with your jupiter notebook and restart the kernel I believe this will solve the issue.

Comment: Ah thank you dude... I already read about that but I always looked in the wrong directory. And my dumbass named some python file "numpy.py" ... "scipy.py" and I was like: "Yeah im going to rename them later when I work on them again." But this caused the whole problem. Thank you for that one man